# What is the equivalent of Java Object in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, casting, sprite-kit

I'm a noobie in Swift. I would like to pass an instance of GameViewController or GameScene to a HelperClass as follows. In java I could use `Object` for this. How is this done in Swift?

```
func getHighscores(leaderboardID: String, caller: **whatTypeHere**) {
...
}
```

so basically I want to notify the right caller when I get the highscores from the GameCenter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand you want "caller" to be any type you want.
In this case you need to use "AnyObject" type here.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Answer (score 1):

AnyObject is the type for "could be anything" in Swift. What you probably actually want is to define a Protocol that both GameViewController and GameScene implement:

```
protocol HighScoreReceiver {
    func gotNewScores(scores:[Int])
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, HighScoreReceiver {
    func gotNewScores(scores: [Int]) {
        // do something here
    }
}

class GameScene: HighScoreReceiver {
    func gotNewScores(scores: [Int]) {
        // do something here
    }
}

class Helper {
    func getHighscores(leaderboardID: String, caller: HighScoreReceiver) {
        //get the scores, then...
        caller.gotNewScores(scores)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an instance of that class you can do it as such. All classes are objects of course, and `UIViewControllers` are no exception.

```
func getHighscores(leaderboardID: String, caller: GameViewController) {
    // call some method in caller like 'caller.refreshHighScore()' 
}
```

If you want to call that method from within the GameViewController class you can do so like this:

```
getHighscores("str", caller: self)
```

If you need to 'notify' a class of something you can use NSNotificationCenter. Here is a  [resource](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/)  to get you started.